# How to link standalone nodejs files to main nodejs server?

Tags: node.js

I am creating a node.js project with the ability to upload files and access a mysql database. The functions are finished and work as standalone files. So far I am able to access different html pages but I'm not sure how to include the nodejs upload and access functions. The functions will be used on different pages than the home page. All of the tutorials I've found establish a server, create the function and everything else all in one file. I'm assuming this is strictly for learning purposes.

Comment: You can make modules and import them in your main file with `require()`. See:https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: @RaphaMex Thanks! That helped point me in the right direction. I was improperly structuring my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of researching the structure of node.js, I realized the format of node.js projects is different than other languages. Modules are created, then imported into main to be called when necessary. I was expecting each page to have their own module imports declared in a separate page.